# shell/command modules not providing output from playbook on Raspberry Pis

Tags: ansible

Using Ansible 2.11.6 from Ubuntu. I have two Raspberry Pis in `inventory`. One is an older Pi3 with Stretch; the other a Pi4 with Buster.

```
$ ansible -i inventory -m shell -a "df -h" all
```

shows the result of `df -h` for both Pis, as expected. But

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory main.yml
```

where `main.yml` is

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: show disk space
      shell:
        cmd: df -h
```

after gathering facts, shows

```
TASK [show disk space] *******************
changed: [pi4]
changed: [pi3]
```

without showing the output of `df -h`.

I've tried `command:` instead of `shell:`. I've tried `executable: /bin/bash`. No difference. The same `main.yml` works with a Vagrant ansible provisioner when building an Ubuntu VM, and shows `df -h` output.

What am I missing?

**Update** This was a mistake on my end. The Vagrantfile template I'd been using included `ansible.verbose = true`. Remove that, and everything behaves consistently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the default verbosity task results are not shown by the `default` stdout callback. Ad hoc commands normally use the `minimal` callback, which has different behaviour. If you are seeing it in the Vagrant output it is either using a different callback or running with a higher verbosity, where more information is displayed:

```
ec2-user@pandora ~ $ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [command] *****************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```
ec2-user@pandora ~ $ ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=minimal ansible-playbook test.yml
localhost | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
Filesystem                                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                                   3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                      3.9G  272K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                      3.9G  8.9M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                                      3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1                              12G  7.3G  4.8G  61% /
/dev/nvme1n1                                40G  9.0G   32G  23% /home
fs-c2c955bb.efs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:/  8.0E     0  8.0E   0% /ammit
tmpfs                                      788M     0  788M   0% /run/user/1913323
tmpfs                                      788M     0  788M   0% /run/user/257994
tmpfs                                      788M     0  788M   0% /run/user/1000
```

```
ec2-user@pandora ~ $ ansible-playbook test.yml -vvv
ansible-playbook [core 2.11.5] 
  config file = /home/ec2-user/ansible-aws/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/ec2-user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/ec2-user/ansible-aws/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/ec2-user/ansible-aws/ansible/collections
  executable location = /home/ec2-user/ansible-aws/.venv/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.8.5 (default, Feb 18 2021, 01:24:20) [GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-12)]
  jinja version = 3.0.2
  libyaml = True
Using /home/ec2-user/ansible-aws/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
Skipping callback 'default', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.

PLAYBOOK: test.yml *************************************************************
1 plays in test.yml

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************
META: ran handlers

TASK [command] *****************************************************************
task path: /home/ec2-user/test.yml:4
Using module file /home/ec2-user/ansible-aws/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible/modules/command.py
Pipelining is enabled.
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: ec2-user
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-gljjnrdznzzibrxampvyyzigtjnozzra ; /home/ec2-user/ansible-aws/.venv/bin/python'"'"' && sleep 0'
changed: [localhost] => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": [
        "df",
        "-h"
    ],
    "delta": "0:00:00.004672",
    "end": "2021-10-20 12:22:07.355248",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "df -h",
            "_uses_shell": false,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "strip_empty_ends": true,
            "warn": false
        }
    },
    "msg": "",
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2021-10-20 12:22:07.350576",
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "Filesystem                                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on\ndevtmpfs                                   3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev\ntmpfs                                      3.9G  124K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm\$
tmpfs                                      3.9G  8.8M  3.9G   1% /run\ntmpfs                                      3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup\n/dev/nvme0n1p1                              12G  7.3G  4.8G  61% /\n/dev/nvme1n1      
                          40G  9.0G   32G  23% /home\nfs-c2c955bb.efs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:/  8.0E     0  8.0E   0% /ammit\ntmpfs                                      788M     0  788M   0% /run/user/1913323\ntmpfs                      
                788M     0  788M   0% /run/user/257994",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "Filesystem                                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on",
        "devtmpfs                                   3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev",
        "tmpfs                                      3.9G  124K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm",
        "tmpfs                                      3.9G  8.8M  3.9G   1% /run",
        "tmpfs                                      3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup",
        "/dev/nvme0n1p1                              12G  7.3G  4.8G  61% /",
        "/dev/nvme1n1                                40G  9.0G   32G  23% /home",
        "fs-c2c955bb.efs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:/  8.0E     0  8.0E   0% /ammit",
        "tmpfs                                      788M     0  788M   0% /run/user/1913323",
        "tmpfs                                      788M     0  788M   0% /run/user/257994"
    ]
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

You can also explicitly output things using `debug`:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: get disk space
    command:
      cmd: df -h
    register: result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
```

```
ec2-user@pandora ~ $ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [get disk space] **********************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "Filesystem                                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on",
        "devtmpfs                                   3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev",
        "tmpfs                                      3.9G  124K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm",
        "tmpfs                                      3.9G  8.8M  3.9G   1% /run",
        "tmpfs                                      3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup",
        "/dev/nvme0n1p1                              12G  7.3G  4.8G  61% /",
        "/dev/nvme1n1                                40G  9.0G   32G  23% /home",
        "fs-c2c955bb.efs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:/  8.0E     0  8.0E   0% /ammit",
        "tmpfs                                      788M     0  788M   0% /run/user/1913323",
        "tmpfs                                      788M     0  788M   0% /run/user/257994"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: You always learn something new. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: That makes sense, and led me to discover my mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the debug task that would show the output.

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: show disk space
    shell:
      cmd: df -h
    register: df
  - debug:
      var: df
```

Ansible does not show the output of the command directly.

Comment: Thanks. Weird that the Ansible provisioner in Vagrant behaves differently.

Comment: I have no experience with Vagrant, so I can only assume that it's a Vagrant feature to show the output directly. I looked through the [Ansible settings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html) but couldn't find anything that sounds like it would be helpful.